# Convert .htaccess to Nginx.conf Rewrite rule

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have this rule which works as expected in .htaccess with Apache
`RewriteRule ^jobs/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?$  index.php?link1=jobs&page=$1&resource_id=$2 [QSA]`
And it will rewrite this URL http://domain.test/jobs/createcv so that the PHP $_GET looks like this:
[image: PHP var_dump]

Now I want to achieve the same with NGINX for the same URL but it does not work.

Rule: `rewrite ^/jobs/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?link1=jobs&page=$1&resource_id=$2;`

But instead I have this weird result

> array(3) { ["link1"]=> string(7) "jobs" ["page"]=> string(7) "createc" ["resource_id"]=> string(1) "v" }

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite rule got broken during your migration from *Apache* to *NGINX* as it is missing a question mark after the second capturing group.

Add the `?` in the rewrite rule and it should work:

```
location /jobs {
  rewrite ^/jobs/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?$ /index.php?link1=jobs&page=$1&resource_id=$2;
}
```

If the second group is optional then the `v` of `createcv` won't be "eaten" accidently like you described.